# combine cells in xls sheet (xml format)

Tags: php, excel, xls

i have a xls file with a structure like

```
<Workbook>
  <Worksheet>
    <Row>
      <Cell>Data</Cell>
    </Row>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

So i use things like ss:Type, ss:Alignment and so on but how can I combine some cells to one like i can do in excel directly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ss:MergeAcross or ss:MergeDown

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa140066#odc_xmlss_ss:cell

Examples:

http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/XML+TAGS+simplifies+Excel+Download